# Placed images resize on their own when reopening an Illustrator file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, resize

I have a problem that I have been struggling with for some time. We deal with Illustrator files all day that have placed images, either JPEG, TIF, PDF, or EPS formats. On several occasions, when we reopen a file that contains placed images or art, the aspect ratio (height and width) has changed to something completely different.

This is a serious issue that we have been dealing with due to the amount of client files we receive that are built to specific sizes, by the client themselves, and we end up having to "best guess" the exact size and position of the artwork and resend a proof to the client to confirm before we can begin plate production.

Also, at times, the file will come in with a massively larger bounding box than the actual artwork requires.

Anyone else experience anything similar? We REALLY need help!

Comment: How you are sure that the photo is same than the one placed as link?. Is the *.ai file possibly produced with different version of Illustrator?  What forces to use  *.ai files?  PDF is a well known solution for shifting the stuff from the creator to the printer.

Answer (score 1):

When you place an image into Illustrator, you can choose to link or embed the image. If you link it then changes to the image outside of illustrator will affect your illustrator file. If you embed the image then it is "baked in" to the illustrator file and the file will not change if the original image changes.

If you are seeing unexplained changes to images within an illustrator file then I'm guessing its because you've linked them rather than embedding. Perhaps the images you have on your computer are different than the ones your client had on theirs, or someone somewhere is editing the files you linked.

When the bounding box is way too large it may be caused by various reasons: small or individual objects are selected with your object. A large clipping mask is being used, a shadow or glow is not easily visible but is expanding the bounding box, etc.

To solve, try ungrouping, expanding, selecting only the desired object with the direct selection tool. If nothing works you can reset bounding box choose: Object > Transform > Reset Bounding Box.